# How can I separate strings in a string builder?

Tags: loops, text, datagridview, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder I am using and I add to it from a loop that goes through a DataGridView. What I need to do is separate the strings if there are more than one with a ", ". Then I set a label's text from the StringBuilder. Below is a working example without the comma's...

THIS IS THE UPDATED VERSION THAT WORKS GREAT NOW....

```
    Dim strUnits As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim lineCount As Integer = 0

   For i = 0 To dgvLowInventory.RowCount - 1
        If dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value Is DBNull.Value Or dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
            'Skip
        Else
            If lineCount >= 1 Then
                strUnits.Append(", ")
                strUnits.Append("[" & dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & " - " & dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "]")
                lineCount += 1
            Else
                strUnits.Append("[" & dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & " - " & dgvLowInventory.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value & "]")
                lineCount += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    lblTestString.Text = strUnits.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a counter, starting at 0.

Add 1 to the counter every time you append, after you append.

Before appending, if the counter is greater than 0, append a `", "` before appending the string.

Alternatively, use String.Join with `", "`, depending on what language you are programming in there's usually an equivalent to this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was already working with just had to get it in the right spot. What was happening is it would add the comma between the strings, but then also one at the end which I didn't want. I edited the above code to show what I have done and works great. Thanks Again!